# How can I create a dummy that is dependent on an arbitrary number previous values of another variable?

Tags: r, data.table

How can I create a dummy that is dependent on all previous values of another variable, where the number of previous values is arbitrary?

My data looks as follows:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(from = as.Date(c("20020101", "20030101", "20040101", "20050101", 
                                  "20010101", "20020101", "20030101", "20040101", "20050101"), "%Y%m%d"), 
                 to = as.Date(c("20031231", "20041231", "20051231", "20061231", 
                                "20021231", "20031231", "20041231", "20051231", "20061231"), "%Y%m%d"),
                 id = as.factor(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)), 
                 cond = c(F, F, T, F, F, T, T, T, F))

> dt
         from         to id  cond
1: 2002-01-01 2003-12-31  1 FALSE
2: 2003-01-01 2004-12-31  1 FALSE
3: 2004-01-01 2005-12-31  1  TRUE
4: 2005-01-01 2006-12-31  1 FALSE
5: 2001-01-01 2002-12-31  2 FALSE
6: 2002-01-01 2003-12-31  2  TRUE
7: 2003-01-01 2004-12-31  2  TRUE
8: 2004-01-01 2005-12-31  2  TRUE
9: 2005-01-01 2006-12-31  2 FALSE
```

What I need to do is create a dummy where `dum = 1` if `cond == TRUE` for any `s <= t` and `dum = 0` if `cond == FALSE` 0 for all `s <= t`.

```
         from         to id  cond dum
1: 2002-01-01 2003-12-31  1 FALSE   0
2: 2003-01-01 2004-12-31  1 FALSE   0
3: 2004-01-01 2005-12-31  1  TRUE   1
4: 2005-01-01 2006-12-31  1 FALSE   1
5: 2001-01-01 2002-12-31  2 FALSE   0
6: 2002-01-01 2003-12-31  2  TRUE   1
7: 2003-01-01 2004-12-31  2  TRUE   1
8: 2004-01-01 2005-12-31  2  TRUE   1
9: 2005-01-01 2006-12-31  2 FALSE   1
```

I was trying to work with lags, i.e. create `N` lags for each `id` where `N` is the number of periods `i was alive for, however, since the individuals aren't alive for a fixed number of periods this approach got too messy.

---

This is the code I was trying to develop for when all `i`s were alive for the same amount of periods (i.e. all `i`s were alive for 4 periods)

```
dt <- dt[1:8, ]
dum <- c()
# Iterate through all unique IDs
for(i in unique(dt$id)){
  # Subset the data
  dt.tmp <- dt[id == i, ]
  N <- nrow(dt.tmp)-1
  nm <- paste("lag.cond", 1:N, sep = "")
  # iterate through all periods and lag cond
  for(j in 1:N){
    dt.tmp[, (nm[j]) :=  shift(.SD, n = j), by = id, .SDcols = "cond"]
  }
  # If any of the lags are == TRUE => set dum to 1
  dt.tmp[, dum := ifelse(cond | lag.cond1 | lag.cond2 | lag.cond3, 1, 0)]
  dt.tmp[is.na(dum), dum := 0]
  dum <- append(dum, dt.tmp$dum)
}
dt[, dum := dum]
dt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that one instance of cond==TRUE triggers dum = 1, you can use a lesser known friend of `cumsum`, `cummax` which returns the cumulative maximum of a variable:

```
dt[, dum := cummax(as.integer(cond)), by="id"]
```

Or using the back-tick syntax for `:=`

```
dt[, `:=`(dum=cummax(as.integer(cond))), by="id"]
```

As @Frank points out, you don't need the `as.integer` function, since `cummax` will coerce the logical cond into an integer on its own. This would shorten your code to

```
    dt[, dum := cummax(cond), by="id"]
```

in the first version which increases readability.

Comment: `cummax` integerifies for you, try `cummax(c(FALSE,TRUE,FALSE))`

Comment: @Frank integerify, that is an amazing word. thanks, I'll add a note in my answer.